# Handle Nancy error in OnError or OnError.AddItemToEndOfPipeline?

Tags: nancy

The Nancy [documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Application-Before,-After-and-OnError-pipelines) says that you can use `pipelines.OnError += (x, y) =>...` to handle errors, but I have seen some tutorials using `pipelines.OnError.AddItemToEndOfPipeline((x, y) =>...`.

Both seem to result in the error being handled correctly. Is there an actual difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `pipelines.OnError += (x ,y) => ...` adds the handler to the end of the pipeline, just like `pipelines.OnError.AddItemToEndOfPipeline((x, y) => ..)` does.

See the source code: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/ErrorPipeline.cs#L39